# Four level Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance

i've been struggling to understand some piece of code of java that uses inheritance to calculate the output. The code is the following:

```
class A
{
    public int calc(double num) {
        System.out.println("calc de A");
        return (int)(num+1);

    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public int calc(long num) {
        System.out.println("calc de B");
        return (int)(num+2);

    }
}

class C extends B
{
    public int calc(int num) {
        System.out.println("calc de C");
        return num+3;

    }
}

class D extends C
{
    public int calc(float num) {
        System.out.println("calc de D");
        return (int)(num+4);

    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int num1 = 10;
        long num2 = num1;

        A a1 = new D();
        A a2 = new D();

        int result = a1.calc(num1) + a2.calc(num2);

        System.out.println("Numero: "+ result);
    }
}
```

Me and my friends think the output of the console should be:

```
calc de C
calc de B
Numero: 25
```

But we run it in Eclipse and in Ideone (link: http://ideone.com/CTdklv) to test it and the answer given is

```
calc de A
calc de A
Numero: 22
```

Can someone explain why does the output is 22 if the signatures of the methods are different.

We belive that if you call the calc method using and int as the parameter you should go to the calc method of the B class instead of the A class.

I appreceate your help!
Thanks.

Comment: your objects are declared as `A`. Your `calc` method have incompatible signature and therefore are not overriding each other. Hence, only `A.calc` can be called at this point.

Comment: Exactly as @njzk2 said. You don't get polymorphism if you don't override the method properly. And without polymorphism you can't get dynamic dispatch from the base class.

Comment: I know they do not override each other but you call them using different types of numeric values. Should calc(int) call the method corresponding to the B calc method and the calc(float) call the D calc method?

Comment: This is an example to function overloading, what is compile time polymorphism since the compiler knows which function to call based on the arguments during compile time.

Comment: @mfsierpe: `calc(int)` cannot be called because your object is declared as being `A`. To convice yourself of that, try to call you method with different names (since they are not overriding eachother it changes nothing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, which overloads can be called is determined by the type of the reference variable ([15.12.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1)):

> If the form (of the method invocation expression) is *ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier*, then **the class or interface to search is the declared type T of the variable denoted by *ExpressionName*** if T is a class or interface type, or the upper bound of T if T is a type variable.

Since `a1` and `a2` are declared to be `A`, you can assign a `D` to them but you can only call the method from `A`.

You can see that it works this way if you change the types around a little bit:

```
class A {
    void m(int i) {}
}

class B extends A {
    void m(double d) {}
}

A a = new B();

double d = 0d;
a.m(d); // won't compile
        // will say something like
        // 'double can not be converted to int'
```

So if you change `a1` and `a2` to `D`

```
D a1 = new D();
D a2 = new D();
```

the output should be as you expected because the overloads in `B`, `C` and `D` are available to call.

---

Note that it works this way for overrides as well.

```
class A {
    protected void m() {}
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void m() {}
}

// in another package...
B b = new B();
b.m(); // call m because it is public in B
A a = b;
a.m(); // won't compile because it is protected in A
```

Which methods are available is determined by the type of the reference.

Comment: If you assign A a = new B(); in this case and the calc method was properly overrided the a.calc() should call the calc method of B right?

Comment: Kindly consider that class D may *override* a method calc of class A and if a new D is stored in A x, x.calc *will most certainly call D's method calc.*

Comment: @mfsierpe Correct. In your example, the cast just eliminates the search for *overloaded* methods. Try running your example with D a1 =... and D a2 =... and then overload resolution kicks in and you'll get the expected result.

Comment: @mfsierpe For overrides yes, but there are no overrides here so that doesn't apply.

Comment: @laune I can't tell what your comment is intended to address. "Call" is not a technical term. I'm not using it technically either.

Comment: At the time I wrote my comment, you had: "In Java, which methods can be called are determined by the type of the reference variable." I can't tell *how* you used it, but it sure is a "technical term", see the JLS where "method call" abounds. But, meanwhile, you have edited your A considerably.

Comment: @laune The spec describes a method invocation expression which is used to determine a compile-time declaration and then at run time the method is located and invoked. I was puzzled because my original intent was to write a non-technical answer so I deliberately avoided these terms. Anyway thanks for the comments.